# Send JSON data of type arrays with rest_v2

Tags: java, json, rest, jasperserver

I am sending JSON data in rest_v2 to JasperReport Server, to create or modify a user, the Jasper Server page indicates the following structure:

```
{
  "enabled":true,
  "password":"newPassword",
  "roles":[
    {"name":"ROLE_USER"},
    {"name":"ROLE_STOREMANAGER", "tenantId":"organization_1"}]
}
```

There are other additional data, but since they already work for me, I did not put them, here the important thing is the array data, which I have tried several ways but it still does not work for me, this is my code:

```
JSONObject jsonBodyInfo = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonBodyInfo.put("fullName", "adm");
                jsonBodyInfo.put("password", "123");
                jsonBodyInfo.put("roles", );
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }
```

I need to add the topic of roles, any help?

Answer (score 0):

Fix the problem by creating an JSONArray outside and passing it in as follows:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            array.put(new JSONObject().put("name", "ROLE_USER").put("name", "ROLE_PRUEBA"));

            JSONObject jsonBodyInfo = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonBodyInfo.put("fullName", user);
                jsonBodyInfo.put("enable", enabled);
                jsonBodyInfo.put("password", pwd);
                jsonBodyInfo.put("roles", array);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }
```